# Custom loss issues in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I try to implement a custom loss function. The goal of the loss function is to minimize:
loss = max(y_actual,y_predicted)/min(y_actual, y_predicted)

The whole script looks like:

```
def get_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, activation = 'relu', input_dim = len(X[0])))
    model.add(Dense(512,input_dim = 200, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'relu'))
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.02)
    model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer = optimizer)
    return model

def custom_loss(y_actual, y_predicted):
    error = []
    for i in range(len(y_actual)):
        if y_predicted[i] > y_actual[i]:
            error.append(y_predicted[i]/y_actual[i])
        else:
            error.append(y_actual[i]/y_predicted[i])

    return K.mean(error)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run = 1
    X = np.load("vectors.npy")

    with open("target2.pickle", "rb") as file:
        target_dict = pickle.load(file)

    target_strings = [*target_dict]

    Y = np.array([])
    for str in target_strings:
        val = target_dict.get(str)
        Y = np.append(Y, val)


    for i in range(run):
        X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2)
        model = get_model()
        model.fit(X_train, Y_train, verbose=1, epochs = 10)
```

Where custom_loss(y_actual, y_predicted) is the loss function I try to implement. However, when I run the code I get the following error:

```
/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:2261 mean
        if x.dtype.base_dtype == dtypes_module.bool:

    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I would really appreciate some input, and just tell me if you want more information.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error is that you are passing a list to tf.keras.backend.Mean, yet the function requires a tensor.

Firstly I believe you need to transform that list to a tensor, with a certain dtype.

Comment: Yes I started to read about that, do you mean tf.concat? Do you have any tips?